# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no <LIBRARY> in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

### The problem

I've been trying to run a unit test on my own Mac. The test runs fine on Linux servers, but fails locally with the following trace:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no fedel_client in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    ....
```

### What I've tried

#### Copy the `.so` file from the server

I've copied `fedel_client.so` from the server to `/workspace/dapper/java/lib/native/macosx` on my local machine, and added it to the `java.library.path`:

```
-Djava.library.path=/workspace/dapper/java/lib/native/macosx:...
```

#### Create a symlink

I've created a symlink from `fedel_clinet` to `fedel_clinet.so`, in case that Java is looking for the former (without the `.so` extension).

#### Add the `.so` directory to .bashrc

I've tried adding `.so` directory to `PATH`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Users/adamatan/workspaces/trunk/dapper/java/lib/native/macosx
```

And to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/adamatan/workspaces/trunk/dapper/java/lib/native/macosx"
```

#### Print the `java.library.path`

I've printed `java.library.path`, to see if the changes in the Eclipse environment were propagated to the JVM:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

And got:

```
/workspace/dapper/java/lib/native/macosx:....
```

The exact values I placed in the Eclipse configuration.

### Debugging ideas?

I got the exact same error with all the aforementioned solutions. Any idea how to debug this problem? Can I get a more verbose error message from Java? Is the file not found, or not loaded? If it isn't loaded, why is that?

Comment: It should definitely be looking for the library *with* the .so extension. One question - did you recompile the library for OS X, or just copy the one from linux? If you just copied the linux one, that's probably the problem.

Comment: I didn't recompile it, but is there a way to get a more verbose output from `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek: no, actually, `.so` is not the extension of a shared library on Mac OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be reading you wrong, but it sounds like you've copied the native library (`libfedel_client.so`) from the Linux server to your own Mac.  If this is the case, this will certainly not work.  You cannot use a Linux native library on your Mac, you will need to recompile it on the Mac to produce a `libfedel_client.dylib`.

Depending on the version of the Apple Java runtime you're using, you may need to use the `.jnilib` extension.  Early runtimes used the `.jnilib` extension instead of `.dylib`, and both extensions are still supported (although `.dylib` is now the default.)